# problems with setting up google analytics analytics.js to send events on page load

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, analytics.js

I'm trying to setup an analytics event that happens on page load which I am firing via window.onload if there is no other js on the page or via $(document).ready() if jQuery is loaded.

The analytics loads and works fine and is using **analytics.js** (not ga.js).  When I try to send events back to analytics, I use this command

```
ga('send', 'event',    {'hitType': 'event',
                        'page': '/checkout/', 
                        'eventCategory': 'Forms',
                        'eventAction': 'formload',  
                        'eventLabel': 'Loaded checkout form correctly'});
```

When I look on the analytics dashboard it tells me that 2 of my visits sent events, but then all of the other events stats are 0.  So in essence I am getting nothing logged.

Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine for me. 
I assume by dashboard you are referring to the real-time one? If it's showing up in there fine, including the dimensions you are passing, then you are all good.

I'd say give it a couple of days, GA Universal processing is quite slow.

Comment: thanks for your reply, gives me some faith.  I'll keep an eye on the dashboard.  It's been since yesterday round midday since I sent the last event to google analytics, so I will keep an eye on it over the coming days.

Comment: My GA Universal account runs 2 days behind as a constant. I ended up deploying both versions of GA tracking (ga.js and analytics.js) pushing  to 2 separate accounts. For events I just push to both of them.

Comment: It was that my site was not running universal and was ditching the push, so I updated it to universal and 24hrs later everything was cool